# Variable 'btnsave' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, variables, button, android-studio

I have the above error on my code. I have tried fixing this by declaring my btnsave as final, but then I get two other errors saying:

> Unknown class: 'btnsave'
>
> Not a statement

Any idea how I fix this error?

```
btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int clicks = 0;
                    clicks++;

                    if (clicks >= 5){
                        btnsave.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putInt("clicks", clicks);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });
```

Comment: You did not include the declaration of "btnsave" in the code you posted.

Comment: Use `((Button)view).setEnabled(false)` or declare `btnsave` class level variable

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK That has solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two options. You can declare your button as finale in this way:

```
final Button btnSave;
```

Or you can declare your button as an attribute of the class (Activity, Fragment or whatever) this way:

```
private Button btnSave;
```

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
if (clicks >= 5){
                    btnsave.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Changed working code:

```
if (clicks >= 5){
                   ((Button)view).setEnabled(false)
                }
```